# Select data based on time in timezone

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to make a script for sending emails at specific time based on timezone saved in `users` table.

I have two tables:

```
users -> id, firstname, lastname, email,  ... , timezone (VARCHAR; America/New_York, Europe/Berlin, ...)
settings -> id, user_id, email_daily_events (TIME), email_daily_task (TIME)
```

I want to retrieve all fields from `settings` table based on time in user's timezone.

In `settings.email_daily_events` and `settings.email_daily_task` are stored times when the mail should be sent. The script is executed with cron every minute.

When the script will retrieve some fields it will send some other data to user's email address.

Whole CMS runs on NodeJS and Sequelize.

I really have no idea how to do it, any idea would be very appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I suggest the following modules :

## [`node-cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)

```
var cron = require('node-cron');
cron.schedule('* * * * *', function(){
  console.log('running a task every minute');
});
```

---

## [`nodemailer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer)

[Simple example : sending a text/html email using node](https://nodemailer.com/about/#example)

---

## [`timezone`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timezone)

> Format time in JavaScript using the IANA time zone database.

```
var tz = require('timezone/loaded'),
    equal = require('assert').equal,
    utc;

// Get POSIX time in UTC.
utc = tz('2012-01-01');

// Convert UTC time to local time in a localize language.
equal(tz(utc, '%c', 'fr_FR', 'America/Montreal'),
      'sam. 31 déc. 2011 19:00:00 EST');
```

---

A combination of `node-cron` with `mysql` to perform your query every minute, then use `nodemailer` to send the emails.

`timezone` might come in handy...